# Unable to add Maven Dependencies into my Eclipse Web Deployment Assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-deployment

trying to get onboard at new job. Guide says to add Maven Dependencies into the Deployment Assembly of the project. There should be an option to add java build paths when I press add but no such option appears. Because of this there no maven and i cant launch the local tomcat server. Is there another way to add the Maven Dependencies build path?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW9En.jpg

Comment: Does the project *have* Maven Dependencies understood by Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right you have a maven project?
If is that you must have pom.xml file in your root path project.

If you want to run your maven project:

```
mvn clean package
mvn install
mvn tomcat:run
```

If you want to import your maven project in Eclipse

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

If doesn't work try with this solution from mkyong
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/no-more-mvn-eclipseeclipse-whats-next/

regards.